# Как открыть выдвижное меню на определенную кнопку?

Tags: android, kotlin

В общем суть проблемы печальна. Пришлось мне с недавнего времени писать приложение под Android и решил я обойтись без использования actionBar, из-за чего в скором времени возник вопрос: как открыть выдвижное меню без значка бургера в actionBar? Свою кнопку-бургер я сделал, повесил на неё обработчик, но что туда пихать - понятия не имею :( Методов по типу setExpand и т.п. у NavigationView я не обнаружил. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным и знает ответ, буду очень признателен. Мои рысканья по просторам Интернета как нашего, так и не нашего, ничего не дали.

Comment: Это делается через `DrawerLayout` - он управляет видимостью панелей и у него есть нужные вам методы.

Comment: Большая вам благодарность :)

Comment: Чтобы закрыть выдвижную панель, следует получить ссылку на объект DrawerLayout и вызвать его метод closeDrawer().